# PHP cookies: Is it possible to set a cookie in only some subdirectories?

Tags: php, cookies

Good morning everyone,

Simple question. I'd like to set a cookie for some of my site, but not all subdirectories. For instance, I'd like to set the cookie accesslevel for the root of my site:

```
setcookie("accesslevel", $accesslevelnumber, $cookielifespan, "/");
```

But not have it accessible in a testing subdirectory, "/testingsite". Is that even possible, or if I set a cookie, I have to accept that it's set in all subdirectories? Thanks, everyone.

Comment: cookie is per domain. So, cookies can be accessed in your subdirectories as well using $_COOKIE

Comment: There is a `path` parameter to cookies, however all children of that path also get it which isn’t what you want. There’s no opposite of it, “this exact directory only”.

Comment: Ok. Oh well. That's a shame. Thanks for the info though!

Comment: Maybe I can do a workaround where I can set the cookies for that subdirectory to some value the site doesn't accept. If it can't be blank, I can set it to "dontgiveaccess" or something.